# Vlookup limitations- want to transfer backwards

Tags: excel, vlookup

Can Vlookup process data backwards or is the logic always to go forwards?

Ie:

I have data that has to go both ways on another sheet. They need to be linked by the same number but the project requires it to read left to right and right to left

So

1 blue car
2 red car
3 green car

and then the mirror

car Blue 1
car red 2
car green 3

is it possible to populate a sheet using the digits as reference from a list or do I need to make another sheet to change that all around for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Vlookup can only go to the right.

Match and Index will let you go left.

Looks like:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$100,MATCH("Blue",$C$1:$C$100,0),1)
```

This would match the color Blue in Column C and return the data in Column A (first column of the specified range).

You can replace the training 1 with another match to dynamically find the column you want to pull data from.

Comment: can I get Vlookup to select a range of cells to add from..so instead of one column..it will add say 3 columns of information?

Comment: You could just have 3x vlookup and concatenate them like =vlookup(...)&vlookup(...)&vlookup(...)

Comment: tHANKS jESSE, ITS BEEN 8 YEARS SINCE i USED ANY OF THIS LAST.